# UIViewRepresentable not working in a modally presented SwiftUI View

Tags: swiftui, combine, observableobject

in order to customise a `UISlider`, I use it in a `UIViewRepresentable`. It exposes a `@Binding var value: Double` so that my  view model (`ObservableObject`) view can observe the changes and update a `View` accordingly.

The issue is that the view is not updated when the `@Binding` value is changed. In the following example, I have two sliders. One native `Slider` and one custom `SwiftUISlider`.

Both pass a binding value to the view model that should update the view. The native `Slider` does update the view but not the custom one. In the logs, I can see that the `$sliderValue.sink { ...`  is correctly called but the view is not updated.

I noticed this is happening when the presenting view has the `@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>` property. If I comment it out, it works as expected.

[image]

A complete sample code to reproduce this is

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresentingModal = false

    // comment this out
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show modal") {
                isPresentingModal = true
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingModal) {
            MyModalView(viewModel: TempViewModel())
        }
    }
}

class TempViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var sliderText = ""
    @Published var sliderValue: Double = 0
    private var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

        init() {
            $sliderValue
                .print("view model")
                .sink { [weak self] value in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    print("updating view  \(value)")
                    self.sliderText = "\(value) C = \(String(format: "%.2f" ,value * 9 / 5 + 32)) F"
                }
                .store(in: &cancellable)
        }
}

struct MyModalView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TempViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("SwiftUI Slider")
            Slider(value: $viewModel.sliderValue, in: -100...100, step: 0.5)
                .padding(.bottom)

            Text("UIViewRepresentable Slider")
            SwiftUISlider(minValue: -100, maxValue: 100, value: $viewModel.sliderValue)
            Text(viewModel.sliderText)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct SwiftUISlider: UIViewRepresentable {
    final class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var value: Binding<Double>
        init(value: Binding<Double>) {
            self.value = value
        }

        @objc func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
            let index = Int(sender.value + 0.5)
            sender.value = Float(index)
            print("value changed \(sender.value)")
            self.value.wrappedValue = Double(sender.value)
        }
    }

    var minValue: Int = 0
    var maxValue: Int = 0

    @Binding var value: Double

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISlider {
        let slider = UISlider(frame: .zero)
        slider.minimumTrackTintColor = .systemRed
        slider.maximumTrackTintColor = .systemRed
        slider.maximumValue = Float(maxValue)
        slider.minimumValue = Float(minValue)

        slider.addTarget(
            context.coordinator,
            action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged(_:)),
            for: .valueChanged
        )

        adapt(slider, context: context)
        return slider
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISlider, context: Context) {
        adapt(uiView, context: context)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> SwiftUISlider.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(value: $value)
    }

    private func adapt(_ slider: UISlider, context: Context) {
        slider.value = Float(value)
    }
}

struct PresentationMode_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In in the `updateUIView` of the `UIViewRepresentable`, I also need to pass the binding to the new instance of the `SwiftUISlider`:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISlider, context: Context) {
    uiView.value = Float(value)

    // the _value is the Binding<Double> of the new View struct, we pass it to the coordinator 
    context.coordinator.value = _value
}
```

The `SwiftUI.View` can be recreated at any time and when it happens the `updateUIView` is called. A new View struct has a new `var value: Binding<Double>` so we assign it to our coordinator

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that the inclusion of `@Environment(\.presentationMode)` causes the `ContentView`'s body to recompute as soon as a model is presented. (I don't know exactly *why* that happens; maybe because there's a change in the presentation mode when `sheet` is shown).

But when that happens, it initiates the `MyModalView` twice, and with **two separate instances** of `TempViewModel`.

On the first `MyModalView`, the view hierarchy with `SwiftUISlider` is created. This is where the `Coordinator` is created and a binding (bound to the first instance of `TempViewModel`) is stored.

On the second `MyModelView`, the view hierarchy is the same, so it doesn't call `makeUIView` (that's only called when view first appears), and only `updateUIView` is called. As you correctly noted, updating the binding to now-the-second instance of `TempViewModel` solves it.

So, one solution is what you did in your other answer - basically re-assign the binding to the new object's property (which, btw, also releases the old object). **This solution actually feels to me like the right thing to do anyway.**

But for completeness-sake, another approach is not to make multiple instances of `TempViewModel`, for example, by using a `@StateObject` to store the view model instance. This could be either inside the parent `ContentView`, or inside `MyModalView`:

```
// option 1
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresentingModal = false
    @StateObject var tempViewModel = TempViewModel()

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        // ...
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingModal) {
            MyModalView(viewModel: tempViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

```
// option 2
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresentingModal = false
    @StateObject var tempViewModel = TempViewModel()

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        // ...
    
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingModal) {
            MyModalView()
        }
    }
}

struct MyModalView: View {
   @StateObject var viewModel = TempViewModel()

   // ...
}
```

Comment: yes your solution also works but involves using `@StateObject` which is not available in iOS 13.

Comment: @Jan, using a `@StateObject` isn't requirement. My broader point was to point out that `TempViewModel` is being instantiated twice, which was the root cause of the issue you had. Your solution patches the effect of that problem, but a comprehensive approach would be to also remove the problem to begin with